# Blazor RoleClaims Policy Not Working on Api end point

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, claims-based-identity

I have application authorizing users based on role claims they owned.

I have following set up

I. Server Side

I have registered policy for startup class

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(Permissions.Products.Create, policy => policy.RequireClaim("Permissions", Permissions.Products.Create));
            options.AddPolicy(Permissions.Products.Edit, policy => policy.RequireClaim("Permissions", Permissions.Products.Edit));
            options.AddPolicy(Permissions.Products.View, policy => policy.RequireClaim("Permissions", Permissions.Products.View));
            options.AddPolicy(Permissions.Products.Delete, policy => policy.RequireClaim("Permissions", Permissions.Products.Delete));

        });
```

This is the api controller method.

```
 // GET: api/Products
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize (Policy = Permissions.Products.View)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Product>>> GetProducts()
        {
            return await _context.Products.ToListAsync();
        }
```

This is my blazor component

```
@page "/product-list"
```

@inject HttpClient client
@inject IJSRuntime js

```
<h3>Products</h3>
<small>Add as many products as you wish.</small>
<div class="form-group">
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="product/create"><i class="oi oi-plus"></i> Create New</a>
</div>
<br>

@if (products == null)
{
    <text>Loading...</text>
}
else if (products.Length == 0)
{
    <text>No Records Found.</text>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (Product product in products)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@product.Id</td>
                    <td>@product.Name</td>
                    <td>@product.Type</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="product/edit/@product.Id">Edit</a>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(() => Delete(product.Id))">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
}
@code {
    Product[] products { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        products = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Product[]>("api/products");
    }

    async Task Delete(int productId)
    {
        var product = products.First(x => x.Id == productId);
        if (await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", $"Do you want to delete {product.Name}'s ({product.Id}) Record?"))
        {
            await client.DeleteAsync($"api/products/{productId}");
            await OnInitializedAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I tested by login into superuser which grants all permissions (claims).

I get the user cookies attached to postman.

When I send the request to that controller. it resulted as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>PermissionBlazorApp</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="PermissionBlazorApp.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you are using identityserver you need to set the required claims by the API 
it looks the token doesn't have the required claims , you could check the content of your token on jwt.io

Comment: @Sras, how do you grant all permissions, and how do you configure the authentication in startup, can you show these code in this question?

Comment: I made it working because I had typo "Permission" not "Permissions"

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools to check if there have some error in the console panel and check the http request status. Besides, check the Startup.Configure method, have you ever add the `app.UseAuthentication();app.UseAuthorization();`, and notice the [Middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).